# How does this callback call work in Node.js with mongo .find call

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

**models/category.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Category Schema
var categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  },
  created_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

var Category = module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);

// Get Categories
module.exports.getCategories = function(callback, limit) {
  Category.find(callback).limit(limit).sort([['title', 'ascending']]);
}
```

**routes/categories.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

Category = require('../models/category.js');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Category.getCategories(function(err, categories) {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    res.render('categories', 
      { 
        title: 'Categories',
        categories: categories
      });
  });
});

router.post('/add', function(req,res) {
  res.send('Form Submitted');
});

module.exports = router;
```

I got a few questions about this code

a) how does the callback mechanism work from routes/categories.js when we pass that callback function to models/category.js in Category.find(callback). That seems bizarre to me since we are doing a whole res.render which becomes part of Category.find() ?

b) Where is limit specified?

c) Why isn't there var in front of Category = require('../models/category.js');

Comment: a) it is just javascript, .find check type of parameter and return all if there is no query. b) limit is undefined in your case. c) also it is javascript, it will be module level variable in nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) that is indeed what happens, and is good: `res.render` will not get called until the `find()` operation executes on the database and a result is sent back for the mongoose code to return to you. You want to run the callback function *after* you get the result for your query, and so calling `res.render` before would be much more bizarre.

b) in the documentation. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find yields a Query object, which may be *synchronously* (i.e. before the query is actually made to resolve at the database) further specified with `where`, `limit`, etc.

c) because someone got lazy. In this example it doesn't actually make a difference because without `var` (or `const` or `let` in modern JS) a variable declaration is tacked onto the local context, which in your file is the `routes/categories.js` module context, and because `Categories` is declared at the top of that scope, `var` doesn't change where the variable ends up being bound. But it's lazy, and for good example code, that *should* have `var` in front of it.